# Open multiple files at once in a tab and split in Vim

Tags: vim

I'm wondering, if I have already open two files in Vim with a vertical split, but I want to open another two files in an extra tab and split those two files in vertical window, how can I do it?

I know I can do:

```
:tabnew file1
:vsp file2
```

Is there a way to do it one-line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but it is one line:

```
:tabnew file1 | vsp file2
```

See

```
:help :bar
```

Answer (score 3):

I just found a similar method, using the command-line pipes, but I think it's a lot more powerful:

```
:tabnew | args views/* | vertical all
```

This opens a new tab, then loads all the files in the `views` directory. Instead of passing a glob to `args` we can specify separate files. `vertical` splits the pane into separate vertical windows, which is what I prefer. `all` tells it to use all the files passed by `args`.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "in one line", I suspect you are not just talking about using a vertical bar character `|` instead of a newline. Rather, I suspect you are looking for a shorter way of performing your task.

You can get what you want by combining the existing suggestions into a user-defined command (see `help :command`). User-defined commands must start with a capital letter.

For example, if you are a C++ programmer, it may be that you like to open a new tab that has the implementation and header files side-by-side. At that point you can define a command such as  this in your `.vimrc`:

```
:command -nargs=1 -complete=file Tabv tabe <args>H | vs <args>C
```

Which can be used thus:

```
:Tabv Foo
```

to open `Foo.C` on the left and `Foo.H` on the right in a new tab.

If your typical usecase is not this specific, it may be more difficult to save keystrokes. Since you are asking this on SU instead of SO, perhaps you are not a programmer, but hopefully you can adapt this suggestion to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from TTM's comment, my two cents here (open all `.c` files in `src` in one tab and all `.h` files in `inc` in another tab):

```
:argadd | :tabnew | args src/* | :argadd | :tabnew | args inc/*
```